# How to stop Plotly Scatter from creating non-existing X values

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I've tried googling this and have implemented all the supposed fixes I've found: Setting `tickvals` and `connectgaps` but it hasn't resolved the issue.

I have a dataset of about 100 rows with property transaction values from 1998, 1999, and 2020. However, Plotly insists on creating every year between 1999 and 2020 even though it doesn't exist in the dataset.

Here is my chart code:

```
def scatter(df):
    """
    Must take in a df with property_type, year, price_paid
    """
    figs = []

    for prop_type in df['property_type'].unique():
        df_filt = df[df['property_type'] == prop_type]
        figs.append(
            go.Scatter(x=df_filt['year'],
                       y=df_filt['price_paid'],
                       mode='markers',
                       marker=dict(
                           size=15,
                           opacity=0.5,
                           line=dict(
                               width=1,
                               color='darkSlateGrey'
                           )
                       ),
                       name=prop_type,
                       connectgaps=True)
        )

    layout = go.Layout(width=1000,
                       height=600)

    fig = go.Figure(data=figs, layout=layout)

    fig.update_xaxes(tickmode='array',
                     tickvals=[n for n in range(len(df_filt['year'].unique()))],
                     ticktext=[n for n in df_filt['year'].unique()])

    chart = pyo.plot(fig, output_type='div', include_plotlyjs=True)

    return chart
```

However here is what it shows..

[image]

All help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the xaxis `'type': 'category'`?

Comment: Thank you, yes! That has worked. Edit: How do I select your comment as the answer?

Comment: Excellent, glad it’s helped you!  Have just popped a proper answer on for you.  Cheers mate.

Comment: Welcome! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution might be (and per your comment, definitely is) as simple as adding the following to the `xaxis` layout:

```
'type': 'category'
```